# Edit GMB OAuth Scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I am using OAuth 2.0 to get access to view, create, edit and delete our clients/users' GMB listings. But I don't want to get access to delete their listings/locations, only want to get access to view, create, and edit.
In the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oawG4.png) I attached, you can see, google ask for delete permission also, so how I can edit scopes to not get permission for delete. Google should show only text for view, create and edit.
This is the [scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage)](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage) I am using for all permissions of GMB listings.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no sub-scope that offers what you are looking for.

NB: You should be using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage instead of the "plus" version as that one is deprecated.